# Psd to pdf selectable text

Tags: pdf, adobe, photoshop, psd

I'm using photoshop from a long time but i have never done this before. Actually i have made an image for my website using photoshop but some of my colleagues want to copy some text from the image.  So, I have tried to save as pdf from photoshop but the text in not selectable, Is there any way in the settings before saving as pdf or any other easy way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some Online services Like [Project Naptha](https://projectnaptha.com/) for this, Basically Photoshop cant make text *selectable* after Saving this.
you can save picture without **Text** and then stick **text** with other apps like *Microsoft Word*. 
More info : [how-to-make-text-in-pdf-selectable](https://support.draw.io/questions/3375234/how-to-make-text-in-pdf-selectable)

Comment: First of all thanks for reply. Project naptha is a servie which let me work like this i mean i can copy paste text from pics but i want to make an image like this so everybody (customers) can copy text. If i save as pdf from Microsoft word the exported file will have selectable text?.

Comment: Got it. yes, insert a **textbox** and paste your text then set fill to _no_ _fill_ (and change text-wrapping) so you can put this where you want on the picture you added before. Finally save it as PDF. all text are **selectable** in this way ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Open the PSD file by Adobe Illustrator, then save as pdf. I tried and it worked

Comment: @sandro this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: It worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, The problem was with any text layer that had **'faux'** styles.  That is Bold and Italic applied as a style, rather than using the specific styled font from the font family.   After removing all of the faux character styles the file converted beautifully to PDF retaining all of the text as selectable and the printing is high-resolution vector text.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way I used, is to use an online PSD editing platform (free / drag & drop) like:

> https://www.photopea.com/

**Steps:**

- Go to the given website.
- Upload your PSD file.
- Go to File menu > Export as > PDF.
- Uncheck the "Vectorize text" checkbox in case it was checked.
- Save the exported file to your location.